# Ajuda na comparação de variável randomizada

Tags: c#, random

Estou fazendo um jogo das cores, nele tenho um random que randomiza botões em uma determinada sequencia.

O valor desses botões são concatenados na variavelX que armeza minha determinada sequencia.

ex:

```
  botão1 = "1";

  botão2 = "2";

  botão3 = "3";

  botão4 = "4";

variavelX = 32131 // variavelX recebe a ordem da sequência randomizada, que no exemplo foi 32131
```

Preciso fazer com que usuário de meu sistema aperte nos botões que foram sorteados, ou seja, na mesma ordem randomizada e se acertar, atribui 10 pontos na label lblPontuacao

Exemplo:

```
variavelX = 32131
// Jogador precisa clicar na seguinte sequência, 3 (botão3), 2 (botão2), 1 (botão1), 3 (botão3), 1 (botão1), e se ele acertar, é atruibuido 10 pontos
```

já fiz debug e constei que as variaveis está passando os valores corretamente porém estou com duvidas de como farei a comparação dessas variaveis, e de como será o if para verificar se elas estão corretas.

A lógica que eu estou utilizando é a seguinte:

Este é a comparação que estou utilizando para ver se o usuário acertou a sequência, mas está errada

```
if (botao.Name == "btnAmarelo")
        {
                ordem1 = ordem;
                if (ordem1 == ordem)
                {
                    lblPontuacao.Text = "10";
                }
        }
```

Este é o timer que utilizo para piscar as cores (não está o timer inteiro, apenas uma parte)

```
private void timerCores_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Random random = new Random();
        int rand = random.Next(1, 13);

        if (rand == 1)
        {
            timerCores.Start();
            Cores(btnAzul);
            timerCores.Stop();
            lblPreparado.Text = "Clique na sequência";
        }
        else if (rand == 2)
        {
            Cores(btnVermelho);
            timerCores.Start();

        }
        else if (rand == 3)
        {
            Cores(btnVerde);
            timerCores.Start();

        }
    }
```

E este é o método que atribui um valor para as cores piscadas.

```
    public void Posicao(Button botao)
    {

        if (botao.Name == "btnAzul")
        {
            ordem = ordem + "a";
        }
        if (botao.Name == "btnVermelho")
        {
            ordem = ordem + "b";
        }
        if (botao.Name == "btnVerde")
        {
            ordem = ordem + "c";
        }
        if (botao.Name == "btnAmarelo")
        {
            ordem = ordem + "d";
        }

    }
```

Comment: As informações estão muito soltas, está difícil entender o que você fez e onde quer chegar. Você deve [edit] a pergunta incluindo mais detalhes e principalmente o que você fez. Dê uma máximo de informação relevante que puder para podermos ajudar você.

Comment: Minha sugestão é usar algo como uma lista (ou array) para representar sua sequência, e não um número. Você *até pode* codificar uma sequência em um número (ex.: `1243 = 1*1000 + 2*100 + 4*10 + 3`) e usar operações de módulo/resto para acessar os itens individuais, mas na minha opinião isso seria complicar à toa... (a menos que você já esteja fazendo isso, é claro - qual o tipo da `variavelX`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Felipe, acredito que você está criando uma versão eletrônica do famoso jogo "Genius"!
Se este for o caso, talvez o algoritmo usado na solução esteja te levando para um caminho mais longo.

Quando falamos em sequencia, todas elas nos levam a pensar nesses tipos de arranjos na memória: filas, pilhas e listas. Como queremos carregar informações que serão utilizados da forma "primeiro número randômico colocado nela deve ser o primeiro número utilizado", então a organização que estamos buscando é a **pilha**.

Em C#, o objeto que a implementa é o `Queue`. Para adicionar um número na pilha, chamamos a função `.Enqueue()`, e para usar/tirar uma informação, usamos a função `.Dequeue()`.

Veja um exemplo: vamos supor que você queira criar uma sequência de `N` vezes (vamos supor 4 botões diferentes, para 4 cores diferentes, como no Genius):

```
 // nNumeros = quantos números vai ter a sequencia
 Queue CriarSequencia(int nNumeros, int nCombinacoes)
 {
     Random rand = new Random();
     Queue sequencia = new Queue();
     for(int i = 0; i < nCombinacoes; i++) 
     {
         sequencia.Enqueue(rand.Next(1, nCombinacoes));
     }
     return sequencia;
  }
```

Esta lista "enfileira" uma sequencia de `nNumeros`, cuja combinação é entre 1 e `nCombinacoes` (no caso do Genius de 4 cores, `nCombinacoes` = 4).

Quando o usuário clicar em um botão, você precisa ver se o número do botão que ele clicou é o próximo da fila. Portanto você verifica assim:

```
   // usuário clicou no numero X
   int proximoFila = (int)sequencia.Dequeue();
   if(x == proximoFila)
   {
       // usuário acertou...
       if(sequencia.Count == 0)
       {
            // usuário acertou todos!!!! dar mensagem de parabéns!
       }
    }
    else
    {
        // usuário errou... ele perdeu
    }
```

Espero que isso lhe ajude.